# Looking for Jenks Optimization - Data Classification

Tags: php, algorithm, gis, classification

I'm looking for an implementation of the Jenks Optimization algorithm for data classification.

Jenks is used to find "natural breaks" in the data.

I want to create kml maps for the US and color each county based on this algorithm.

I'm using php, but can figure out other languages as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go in python

http://danieljlewis.org/2010/06/07/jenks-natural-breaks-algorithm-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

Here You have PHP
https://github.com/randomdrake/jenks/blob/master/jenks.php

This is implementation of Jenks algorithm.
David Drake made these functions and integrated it with Google API.